# Let $G$ be a group, and $H\leq G$. Is it true that $g_1=g_2 \iff g_1H=g_2H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been doing an exercise and this question came to my mind:

Let $G$ be a group, and $H\leq G$. Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be elements of $G$. Is it true that $g_1=g_2 \iff g_1H=g_2H$?

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts? Is one direction easy? What examples do you know for groups? What happens when $H=G$?

Comment: By $H\le G$, you mean $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, or any subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski It means that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H=\{e\}$ it is clearly true. If $H$ is not $\{e\}$ take $h_1,h_2$ different elements in $H$. We have $h_1H=h_2H=H$. So $g_1H=g_2H$ does not imply $g_1=g_2$

Comment: Then $g_1=g_2 \implies g_1H=g_2H$?

Comment: $g_1=g_2$ definitely implies $g_1H=g_2H$ because $g_1$ is $g_2$.

Comment: The statement $g_1 = g_2 \Rightarrow g_1H=g_2H$ is literally obvious. It has nothing to do with group theory or cosets, it's just obvious!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What does $g\in H$ imply about $gH$?

Answer (score 3):

Take $G=H=\Bbb Z$, $g=1$ and $g_2=-1$. What are $g_1H$ and $g_2H$ in this case?